# How do I use puppet to configure network settings?

Tags: puppet, sles

I have written a module that will configure network settings on my system but I can't apply the manifest because before a manifest is applied it does "facter ipaddress" to find and present global facts.

Does it mean that in order to apply puppet manifest we must have IP configured ?

So I have a system that has no IP address configured and i want to use puppet to configure that IP address for me, for that I am asking user to input IP address which i save in a .csv file, then I am using a template to configure if-eth0 file. Template will do extlookup to fill up the fields in template and template is finally called upon inside a manifest. So the problem is that before anything is applied by puppet, it fails to run with following error

facter ip address unable to resolve IP , reason anonymous

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. If you don't provide any puppet codes or any error messages for your question, you can't get anything, waste your time, and waste our time.

Comment: Its a conceptual question, and I have already mentioned the error if you carefully read the question. Person who has strong conceptual and technical background in puppet should be able to understand easily. What is tough here that you are NOT able to understand ? If you have any question in specific, feel free to ask and I will sincerely answer them. This was we should be able to deliver something meaningful to stackflow subscribers.

Comment: No, the information provided is pretty slim indeed. Please supply the output of `puppet agent --test --debug --verbose --trace` via Pastebin or similar.

Comment: OK, let me put it this way. I am using masterless configuration, so basically puppet apply is the command to apply any manifest withing standalone system which is acting as both master and slave configuration. Now, before any manifest is applied, catalog is compiled and during its compilation, facts of the node are presented including IP address, but in my case catalog compilation is failed because I am Fact ipaddress is not initialized for my OS which is SLES. and so puppet apply command doesn't even begin. It is something related to uninitialized fact facter ipaddress. makes sense now ?

Comment: This is the error what i get when I run facter: "Could not retrieve fact='ipaddress', resolution='<anoymous'>: Network is unreachable -connect(2)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the actual question (if IP is indeed needed). However, if I understand correctly you can try one of the two workarounds:

1. Enable DHCP

This way when your system boots will take a little bit more time (assuming there is no DHCP service on the network). A timeout will occur which, in most of the cases, results in a default IP (169.254.Y.Z if I remember). In this case you may need to stop/kill the dhcp client process before applying static IP or restart the interface to get the new configuration.

2. Assign default static IP

If you know that puppet configuration will be applied no matter what (maybe a call in rc.local?), you can configure your interface with a static IP (ie 10.1.1.10) to avoid the error message. This is temporary since once puppet runs, the correct configuration will be applied.

Hope it helps,

Andreas

Comment: Andreas, that's a good workaround and solved my problem, thanks